# zk - is it possible to add binding to each record in model?

Tags: java, zk, zk-grid

```
<zk>
    <grid width="auto" sizedByContent="true" span="1" sclass="tblWithoutHover">
        <attribute name="onCreate">
            authorPublisherEtcInclude.insertBefore(self, authorBox);
        </attribute>
        <columns>
            <column/>
            <column/>
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <row valign="center">
                <cell colspan="2"><label use="${authorPublisherComponents.originalFieldsLabel}"/></cell>
            </row>
            <row valign="center">
                <label use="${authorPublisherComponents.titleAuthorOriginalLabel}"/>
                <textbox use="${authorPublisherComponents.titleAuthorOriginalTextbox}"/>
            </row>
            <row valign="center">
                <label use="${authorPublisherComponents.mainAuthorOriginalLabel}"/>
                <textbox use="${authorPublisherComponents.mainAuthorOriginalTextbox}"/>
            </row>
            <row valign="center">
                <label use="${authorPublisherComponents.mainAuthorResponsibilityLabel}"/>
                <selectbox use="${authorPublisherComponents.mainAuthorResponsibilitySelectbox}"/>
            </row>
            <row valign="center">
                <label use="${authorPublisherComponents.authorityDatesOriginalLabel}"/>
                <textbox use="${authorPublisherComponents.authorityDatesOriginalTextbox}"/>
            </row>
            <row valign="center">
                <cell>
                    <label use="${authorPublisherComponents.addMainAuthorsOriginalLabel}"/>
                    <toolbarbutton use="${authorPublisherComponents.addAuthorButton}"/>
                </cell>
                <cell id="addAuthorsCell">
                    <grid id="addAuthorsContainer" model="@bind(ivm.inventory.addAuthorsBeans)">
                        <columns>
                            <column/>
                            <column/>
                            <column/>
                        </columns>
                        <rows>
                                <row>
                                    <textbox value="@load(xgbfxb.authorName)" onChange="@command('test', component = self, index=s.index)"/>
                                    <button label="Del" onClick="@command('delAuthor', container=addAuthorsContainer, index=modelIndex )">
                                        <custom-attributes modelIndex="${s.index}"/>
                                    </button>
                                </row>
                        </rows>
                    </grid>
                    <textbox use="${authorPublisherComponents.addMainAuthorsOriginalTextbox}"/>
                </cell>
            </row>
```

Here is part of my zul page. addAuthorsBeans is list of classes with fields. When I change data in my combobox, application call set method for all classes in list, but I want it to call only for corresponding item. Is it possible? Or should I cast black magic with onChange events and ViewModel methods?

Edit (21/12/2013). It works like this: I have got three items 1, 2, 3. Then I activate setAuthor for 2 item. And then application call setAuthor method for 2 item, then for 3 item, then for 1 item and then looking for this method in container.

I have 'black magic' temporary solution to create static variable and change it on first call of setAuthor method and unblock it in container.

But it's not a final solution, because it's consume more resources and really not how should it really works.

**Solution:** if you've got grid with model in another grid it will behaive very strange. So just use listbox instead.

Comment: Just to make that clear: When you select an item in the combobox, then all addAuthorsBeans' authorNames are set to that item?

Comment: I don't tried this, because I'm using combobox for autocomplete. I just type data and with this I get trigger setMethods.

Comment: @Dracontis, did this example helped you with your question?

Comment: @chillworld, I've already changed implementation and I'll stay with it, because even if we haven't uniform coding notations I think I should write something that've already used. But I assume, that your example will be useful for future projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `combobox` will only trigger `item.setAuthorName(...)` of the object witch represent item.
If other setters are called you must have `@NotifyChange` or `@DependsOn` in your ViewModel class linked to this.

edit: try changing:

```
<grid model="@bind(ivm.inventory.addAuthorsBeans)">
```

to

```
<grid model="@load(ivm.inventory.addAuthorsBeans)">
```

**Update** : a working example from me created for this topic : http://forum.zkoss.org/question/90188/notifychange-to-grid-that-is-inside-a-row-of-another-grid/?answer=90284#post-id-90284  ) :

First simple pojo class :

```
package be.chillworld;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author chillworld
 */
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String naam;
    private List<Person> childs = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public Person(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        naam = "test " + id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setNaam(String naam) {
        this.naam = naam;
    }

    public String getNaam() {
        System.out.println("asked getter (naam) of "+ id);
        return naam;
    }

    public List<Person> getChilds() {
        System.out.println("asked getter (childs) of "+ id);
        return childs;
    }

    public void setChilds(List<Person> childs) {
        this.childs = childs;
    }

    public boolean addChild(Person person) {
        return childs.add(person);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + getNaam() + '}';
    }
}
```

then the IndexVM:

```
package be.chillworld;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.zkoss.bind.BindUtils;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.BindingParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;

/**
 *
 * @author chillworld
 */
public class IndexVm {

    private List<Person> persons;
    int i;

    public IndexVm() {
        System.out.println("starting creating list");
        persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Person person = new Person(i);
            person.addChild(new Person(++i));
            persons.add(person);
        }
        System.out.println("ending creating list");

    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    @Command
    public void showIndex(@BindingParam("person") Person person) {
        System.out.println("changed name");
        person.setNaam("Chillworld");
        BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, person, "naam");
    }

    @Command
    public void addChild(@BindingParam("person") Person person) {
        System.out.println("add child");
        Person child = new Person(++i);
        child.setNaam("new child");
        person.addChild(child);
        BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, person, "childs");
    }
}
```

and at last the index.zul :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zk xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul
                   http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul/zul.xsd">
<window border="normal" closable="false"
        apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('be.chillworld.IndexVm')">
    <grid width="1000px" model="@load(vm.persons)">        
        <columns>            
            <column label="naam" /> 
            <column label="add child" />            
            <column label="childs" />        
        </columns>        
        <template name="model" >            
            <row>                
                <textbox value="@bind(each.naam)" /> 
                <button onClick="@command('addChild',person = each)" label="add child"/>                       
                <grid width="400px" model="@load(each.childs)">        
                    <columns>            
                        <column label="naam" />            
                        <column label="button" />        
                    </columns>        
                    <template name="model" var="item">            
                        <row>                
                            <textbox value="@bind(item.naam)" /> 
                            <button onClick="@command('showIndex',person = item)" label="change value"/>        
                        </row>        
                    </template>    
                </grid>           
            </row>        
        </template>    
    </grid>
</window>
</zk>
```

this gives as output (after startup) :

```
changed name
asked getter of 11
changed name
asked getter of 7
changed name
asked getter of 19
```

Greetz chill.

Comment: Have you got an idea how to block this events? Because it's called for every object plus for bean container. It's legacy code, but I don't see any annotations, so it will be a problem to find that place.

Comment: VM is too big, to post it here. I'll try to find out about this annotations. As I remember, load won't help fix it, because I change to bind after this problem appears with load.

Comment: Try removing the model and renderer from combobox

Comment: This is autocomplete options and they do not affect this. I also tried all your advices and nothing works for me.

Comment: When you change the last bind to load, the problem stays? (so you only have @load in zul)

Comment: Oké, I am little confused, what setters are called? The setters of each comboboxitem or multiple authorsbeans?

Comment: It happens when I type something into combobox. Setters of each comboboxitem are called (I edited question with explanation how it works) and last thing is setter in 'inventory' (class-container) is called too, after all setters of each comboboxitem is finished.

Comment: Oké, I got it. I will make sample project when I'm home. This could take a while now with the hollidays. I will post new andere with a sample project.  Greetz chill

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'll use Listbox, as I got example implemented in the project.